# Why should didUpdateWidget be implemented for subscriptions and ChangeNotifiers?

Tags: flutter, provider

I created a custom widget that listens to a `ChangeNotifier` and invokes a provided callback whenever the notifier fires. This is used for performing one-time tasks like navigation when the notifier changes.

Everything seems to work fine, but just by accident I stumbled upon the [documentation of `didUpdateWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didUpdateWidget.html) that states:

> If a State's build method depends on an object that can itself change state, for example a ChangeNotifier or Stream, or some other object to which one can subscribe to receive notifications, then be sure to subscribe and unsubscribe properly in initState, didUpdateWidget, and dispose:
>
> - In initState, subscribe to the object.
> - In didUpdateWidget unsubscribe from the old object and subscribe to the new one if the updated widget configuration requires replacing the object.
> - In dispose, unsubscribe from the object.

I'm handling the first and last point for obvious reasons, but could somebody shed a light on why I also have to implement `didUpdateWidget`? What could go wrong if I don't?

Bonus question: I'm not using provider in my application, yet. Does it offer something like this already out of the box? I couldn't find something like this.

My widget code:

```dart
class ChangeNotifierListener<T extends ChangeNotifier> extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final T changeNotifier;
  final void Function(T changeNotifier) onChanged;

  ChangeNotifierListener(
      {@required this.child,
      @required this.changeNotifier,
      @required this.onChanged});

  @override
  _ChangeNotifierListenerState createState() =>
      _ChangeNotifierListenerState<T>();
}

class _ChangeNotifierListenerState<T extends ChangeNotifier>
    extends State<ChangeNotifierListener<T>> {
  VoidCallback _callback;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => widget.child;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _callback = () {
      widget.onChanged(widget.changeNotifier);
    };
    widget.changeNotifier.addListener(_callback);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.changeNotifier.removeListener(_callback);
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part of the documentation is about how it is feasible that your widget rebuilds with a different parameters.

For example, with `StreamBuilder`, a first build may be similar to:

```dart
StreamBuilder(
  stream: Stream.value(42),
  builder: ...
)
```

And then something changes, and `StreamBuilder` is rebuilt with:

```dart
StreamBuilder(
  stream: Stream.value(21),
  builder: ...
)
```

In which case, `stream` changed. Therefore, `StreamBuilder` needs to stop listening to the previous `Stream` and listen to the new one.

This would be done though the following `didUpdateWidget`:

```dart
StreamSubscription<T> subscription;

@override
void didUpdateWidget(StreamBuilder<T> oldWidget) {
  super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  if (widget.stream != oldWidget.stream) {
    subscription?.cancel();
    subscription = widget.stream?.listen(...);
  }
}
```

The same logic applies to `ChangeNotifier` and any other observable object.

Comment: Thanks, this cleared it up for me. Basically in my implementation, the `changeNotifier` could change and thus I should remove the listener from the old one and attach it to the new one in order to prevent events from the old notifier being delivered instead of the new ones.

Comment: Does provider come with a widget as described in my initial post by any chance, i.e. one that does not rebuild on changes, just fires a callback? Just to make sure I don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: No. But that widget is basically `AnimatedBuilder`